# OnCollisionEnter() not functioning with rigid-body and continuous detection while bouncing..?

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection

So, as the title implies, my OnCollisionEnter is not being called. I'm not sure why. The objects are bouncing off surfaces they contact.

Here's the relevant code:

```
static Rigidbody m_ProjectileRigidbody;
internal void FireProjectile(GameObject projectile, float speed)
{
    projectile.transform.position =
        State.PlayerTransform.position + State.PlayerTransform.forward;
    projectile.transform.rotation = State.PlayerTransform.rotation;

    m_ProjectileRigidbody = projectile.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    m_ProjectileRigidbody.AddForce
        (State.PlayerTransform.forward * speed, ForceMode.Impulse);

    if (State.PlayerState.Consumes)
    {
        State.PlayerState.ConsumeCellEnergy(EnergyConsumption);
        State.PlayerState.GenerateCellHeat(HeatProduction);
    }
}

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    Debug.Log("Collided With: " + collision.gameObject.name);
}
```

[image]

Comment: `Notes: Collision events are only sent if one of the colliders also has a non-kinematic rigidbody attached.` Are you aware of it?

Comment: Yar. That's why I put a screenshot of the prefab. It's not kinematic.

Comment: Are you working with 2D collider? Can we see the object he is colliding with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are working with 2D `colliders` and `rigidbodies`, use `OnCollisionEnter2D` instead of `OnCollisionEnter`.

And make sure in `Edit -> Project Settings -> Physics` the collision matrix is properly set.

And also, double check that:

1. Both objects have `collider`, `rigidbody` properly set up.
2. Both objects are active.
3. You do not accidentally disable `collider`, `rigidbody` or set
   `isKinematic`, `isTrigger` from your script.

Comment: Thanks, I thought only one had to have a rigid body.